# Plotly's hovering causing occulusion

Tags: python, plotly

I am using plotly for displaying simple line graph. When I hover over some data point, it shows the x value of data point on the x axis itself. However the y axis value is displayed on the graph which causes occlusion to other data points.

Is there a way such that the y coordinate value of the data point is displayed on the y axis itself (just like the x coordinate value) so that my plot is not occluded and at the same time I am able to view the coordinates of my data point?

I other words, each of the coordinates highlighted on its own axis (e.g. either with a little window or simply by visualizing the number on the axis as the other labels of the axis). And avoid the pop-up window where the coordinates are visualized will cover part graph

PS: I am not able to accomplish it using hovermode :(